# Python Mock dependencies

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, patch

Hello I am looking for a way to mock functions that are called by a function.
At the moment I only find similar examples like this:

```
def f1():
    a = 'do not make this when f1() is mocked'
    return 10, True

def f2():
    num, stat = f1()
    return 2*num, stat

import mock

print f2() # Unchanged f1 -> prints (20, True)

with mock.patch('__main__.f1') as MockClass: # replace f1 with MockClass 
    MockClass.return_value = (30, True) # change the return value
    print f2() # prints now 60,
```

The problem with this is that the return value of the method is overwritten but the actual logic of the function is still executed.
What happens in the function should be ignored.
In other words I want to overload the function for the test.
Is this a good idea, or are there other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual logic of function is not executed. It will replace target function with new mock object that returns your value when called

```py
def f1():
    a = 'do not make this when f1() is mocked'
    print("should be printed once")
    return 10, True
 
def f2():
    num, stat = f1()
    return 2*num, stat
 
import mock
 
print f2() # Unchanged f1 -> prints (20, True)
 
with mock.patch('__main__.f1') as MockClass: # replace f1 with MockClass 
    MockClass.return_value = (30, True) # change the return value
    print f2() # prints now 60,
```

Output:

```
should be printed once
(20, True)
(60, True)
```

`sohuld be printed once` is printed only one time, hence inner logic is not executed second time when patched.

see execution here https://ideone.com/jRpObT

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works.
I work with more as one file and the problem was the import.

I changed my import:
**from package.file import method # not work**
**import package.file # work**

And instate of **method()**
**use file.method()**

Change this on both sides and it will work.